# https://example.com doesn't make a request to my load balancer but http works

Tags: nginx, domain-name-system, ssl, load-balancing, redirect

This is how my example.com.conf file looks like -

```
upstream web_app_backend {
    ip_hash;
    server <app1 ip>:<port>;
    server <app2 ip>:<port>;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name example.com;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/example.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/example.com.key;
    return 302 http://example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;

    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        proxy_pass  http://web_app_backend;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

what could be going wrong? When i load https://example.com, i see no logs in access.log files and error.log files.

Answer (score 1):

As it turns out my `443` port was blocked.